# Is it possible to highlight customers in Shopify admin customers list?

Tags: shopify

My Shopify app makes some changes for some of the shop customers. 
I want to highlight these changed customers in Shopify admin customers list. Or maybe there is possibility to add an additional column in customers list?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using metafields? I often use them for storing that kind of information